Upload and extract a zip file into Unity WebGL build
Recently I am working in a project , where I have to upload zip file into Unity WebGL build and process the files after extract it. I have try StandalonFileBrowser package for this , but when try to build it shows multiple build issues . Like <.gkt/gkt.h> file not found into library.c file. or something like that.
I have try to browse files by using StandaloneFileBrowser unity package. It's not working when I build . I want to upload zip file and extract it.
